# How to access the built-in .equal() if it's overridden?

Tags: java, equals

So i've created equals() method. If i want to compare 2 objects, they can only see this one. How do i get my object to use the one defined in the object class.

```
public boolean equals(Object object1) {
if(a == object1) {   
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Compare object1 = new Compare("test");
Compare object2 = new Compare("test");
if(object1.equals(object2)
 .................

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i get my object to use the one defined in the object class.

If you don't override `equals` in your class, it will use by default the one declared in closet parent class. If no closest parent class has it then `Object` class has one which will be used.

But if you want to call `equals` from `Object`class in any of the method of your class you need to use `super` which is a reference to parent. You need to use `super.equals()`.

Comment: It will use the one in the closest parent class overriding `equals`, more precisely

Comment: @Dici: Yes you are right.

Comment: Yes, i'd like to use the one in object class. is this correct? if(object1.super.equals(object2))

Comment: @Square-root The implementation in `Object` simply uses `==`.

Comment: @Square-root: If your class or any of its parent class (except Object) has nto overridden `equals` method then by default one from `Object` will be used. The `equals` in Object checks for reference equality which you may not be really needing.

Comment: isn't that compares references rather than values which i'm looking to compare

Comment: @Square-root: You are trying to compare two references which point to two different instances (notice `new`).

Comment: i'm comparing the values that's why i'm using .equal() .. i understand all of your points but i want to call the one in object while keeping my own version of .equal().  is this syntactically correct if(object1.super.equals(object2)) because it tell me the object cannot find the symbol super

Comment: This is not clear... if you want to use the default implementation just use `==` but this is doomed to fail because you know the references are different. What's wrong in your code is your implementation of `equals` which never considers the attributes of your class

Comment: the == will just show me the 2 objects referring to different places in memory.. rather, i'd like to compare the values so == will not help me with that

Comment: @Square-root Then there's no point in using `Object`'s implementation of `equals`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what everyone has been trying to tell you. `Object.equals` uses `==`, so you don't want to use it. You have to override `equals` to take into account the value of the attribute, that's simple as this